# Edit multiple layers in Gimp

Tags: gimp, layers, effects

Is it possible to apply things like brightness/contrast or hue saturation or even filters to more than one layer at a time in Gimp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the GIMP Animation Plug-in (GAP), you will have available a "Filter All Layers" command added to the Filters menu. When you execute the command, you will be presented with a list of all filters available in the Procedural Data Base and be able to choose one of them to be applied to each of the layers in your image...

Comment: links broken :(

Answer (score 1):

[Layer groups](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-groups.html) have a *limited* ability to affect multiple layers. The most useful of these is opacity. Operations such as brightness and contrast are currently layer-only operations in GIMP and will not work on layer groups.

One possible work around is to save settings as a preset when adjusting brightness, and other settings. This will allow you to re-produce the same settings on additional layers (although they must still be applied to each layer one at a time).

Answer (score 0):

G'MIC addon will work for that

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site. We ask that you provide a reasonable amount of detail - a link to the addon and how to use it to solve this problem would go a long way to improve your answer!

Comment: Yea - the stackexchange sites are great but you have to answer and use the site according to reasonably strict rules - see the help section above