# How to change color of multiple text objects at once

Tags: color, gimp, text

I'm using GIMP and I have a lot of text object in a project that must have the same color. Every time I want to change this color I have to select the texts one by one and change it. Is there a way to speed up this operation? Something that let me to change all text color at once?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion current Gimp versions (2.8) doesn't allow multiple layers selection, you can group or chain them (see also [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11249/how-to-select-more-layers-with-gimp)), but this is not the same thing, and you can't change at once the color of grouped of chained text boxes.

A fast way to change is the following:

**1.** Select a text layer

[image: select]

**2.**-**3.** Drag the color from the Toolbox color and drop it onto the image. It should change the color of the selected Textbox. *Note*: this method doesn't work if you have already manually changed the color of the text by selecting some characters or the whole text using the text tool.

[image: drag]

[image: drop]

**4.** Repeat previous steps until done.

See also [here](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-text.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have a similar tip on changing the *font* of multiple text layers? I have about 100 or so and am dreading the thought of going through them 1 by 1 :/

Comment: Have you tried to **Select All in All Layers (Ctrl+Alt+A)** and use the [Text and Font dialog](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html_old/Text-Formatting.html) to set the font? It should work. Note that applies only on unlocked layers.

Answer (score 2):

### Using a layer group:

- Create you text layers using neutral gray (127,127,127)
- Create a layer group
- Move all your text layers to the layer group
- Add a new layer at the top of the group, and set it to "Color" mode
- You can then color all you text layers (and only them) by bucket-filling that layer with the required color
- You can of course use multiple groups

Having an opaque layer above your text layers will make them difficult to move (the Move tool will pick the color layer). Just make the color layer invisible temporarily.
[image]

Note: if starting with black text, use `Lighten only` mode on the color layer.

### Edit: much simpler solution with Gimp 2.10:

- Put all your text layers in layer group
- Add a layer at the top of the group, fill it with the color/pattern/image
- Set the composite mode of that layer to `Clip to back drop` either using the layer attributes dialog (as show) or directly in the right click menu.
- The group is used to limit the scope of the `Clip to backdrop`
- In this method, the colors of the layers are unimportant.

[image]

Comment: Works great ! If your text is black, playing with the layer modes can help find the good option. In my case, the "difference" mode was the right one.

Comment: Which why i recommend that you make your text gray instead. Note that if you use black, "Lighten only" would be the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

I’m using GIMP and I guess I just figured it out how to put color on one group of text layers:

1. Simply put them in one layer group.
2. Make a new layer in that group.
3. Here is the twist: Mark that layer as transparency.
4. On that layer, right-click and select *alpha to selection.*
5. Use the bucket tool to change to your desired color.

Answer (score 1):

Requires script-fu Color Overlay script for Gimp.

Create a layer group, add your text layers to it.

Select group layer (top of 'tree'), Script-Fu > Layer Effects > Color Overlay (select color).  It will change all the text layer colors and does it by adding a new overlay layer.  If you don't like it, you can remove the layer (or change opacity etc or start over.   Nice solution.  You're welcome :-)

Answer (score -3):

Its simple.

Select (shift Select) all your text layers that needs a color change.

Now go to the color picker select your desired color.

You should see the color change reflected on all your text layers.

Comment: I can't select more than one layer at once, also pressing `Shift` when I press on a new text layer the previous one becomes unselected

Comment: @GeoJoy Welcome on GD! Have you tried this operation with the Gimp? Can you tell us more about the Gimp version have you used?

Comment: Selecting multiple layers is not possible. This answer is wrong.