# Copying/Duplicating Multiple Layers in GIMP and Inserting Them

Tags: gimp, layers

Author of [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82830/moving-multiple-layers-in-gimp/82871#82871). Wasn't registered when I made the question, so I can't mark it as answered or comment on it anymore despite using the same email address. jsbueno's answer on that question was extremely helpful, though.

This is in a similar vein to the last question. I want to select multiple layers and physically copy the layer (not the contents of the layer or the flattened result of the layer) and then insert them elsewhere.

Here's an example of what I want using a different application (Krita), to help visualize:

First, I select the layers...

[image: selecting multiple layers in krita]

Then, I copy/duplicate them. Notice how the layers are simply inserted above their current position (aka, below Layer 8). This would be ideal for me.

[image: layers post-duplication]

I can't use layer groups for this, because GIMP treats a layer group as the resultant image of its layers rather than individual layers. This conflicts with certain filters/effects, specifically animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less the same answer then, you have to script it somehow.

Having some free time so did it, see `ofn-reorder-copy-layers` [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/).

It adds two items to your menus:`Image>Copy linked layers` and `Image>Reorder linked layers`. Linked layers will be copied/moved in sequence just above the currently active layer.

For discussion, improvements, etc, see [here](http://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-ofn-reorder-copy-layers)

Answer (score 0):

### You can just use Layer Groups:

1. Add layers to a group.
2. select the group -> CTRL+C -> CTRL+V.

Should copy the layers while keeping them all separated (unmerged).

Hope it helps :)